# Visual Studio Intellisense suggestions disappears immediately after coming up

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense, visualgdb

I am using Visual Studio Community and Visual GDB to code and debug STM32 projects.

###### The problem:

When I type something that is known to Intellisense, (path, variable or anything really), the suggestions come up briefly and then immediately disappear therafter. For that split second I can see that Intellisense has the correct suggestions, but `TAB` or `ENTER` does not work since the suggestions disappear very quickly.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You might try to disable any extensions in Visual Studio.

I had the same problem, surfed around and read in some places that disabling extensions would work.

So I disabled them one by one and the problem was gone.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the suggestion. This did not work for me.

Comment: deleting the .vs folder is additionally always a good trick

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, I noticed that it happens when the suggestion involves the context that is quite long beyond the screen.
Here is how it look like:

---

|Function1(xxx,xx,xxxxx,xxx,xx,xxxxxxxxx, xxx)
|Function2(xxx,xx)             |
|                              |
|______________________________|
Screen
So if it has something like Function1 in that suggestion then it will instantly disappear after popup.
The temporary solution is to separate the long function into 2 functions or more.
I’m also looking for a better solution that might need some setting in the visual studio and make this long function working.